# В чем ошибка в запросе к Mysql на переименование ячейки?

Tags: php, mysql

в POSTe приходят два имени, они присваиваются `$newName` и `$oldName`. Почему так и не доходит запрос к базе данных?

```
$query = "UPDATE
            `img_table`
          SET
            `name` = $newName
          WHERE
            `name` = $oldName";
$updName = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите на сообщение об ошибке mysql, там всё написано будет.

Comment: Запрос вроде синтаксически правильный, за тем исключением, что вы скорее всего не фильтруете входные данные. Если ваши имена содержат кавычки, то запрос не сработает и возможно выполнение sql инъекции. А так всякое может быть: нет подключения к бд, нет таблицы или столбца.

Answer (score 0):

У вас все почти правильно... если бы вы использовали PDO и конструировали запрос, то ошибки бы не было, а так как вы пишите напрямую, то учитывайте тип передаваемых параметров: строка передается в кавычках...

```
$query ="UPDATE
           `img_table`
         SET
           `name` = '$newName'
         WHERE
           `name` = '$oldName'";
$updName = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: А потом в запросе появится д'Артяньян и опять всё поломает.

Comment: '".$newName."' не?